# Notes error: Field is too large (32K) when setting signature on Mac

Tags: osx-mavericks, lotus-notes

When I try to set my signature in IBM Notes 9 on Mac (More > Preferences > Mail > Signature), I'm getting this error message:

```
Notes error: Field is too large (32K) or View's column & selection formulas are too large
```

[image]

I've tried setting all three signature fields (rich text, plain text, html file) to blank but the error still happens.

Is there a different field I need to set to blank? I'm not seeing any other long fields in any of the tabs in this preferences dialog.

When I set a signature and ignore the error, the signature persists until I restart Notes.

None of the Google hits for this error mention setting a signature or running on Mac. I have just migrated from Notes 9 on Windows to Notes 9 on Mac.

Comment: Support determined that my profile was corrupted and ran some slow process to uncorrupt it. The issue is resolved, but I'm not sure what the generic steps to resolve would be.

Comment: Sometimes you can find a field that isn't fill out correctly, but usually deleting the calendar profile is necessary to resolve the issue. It seems to happen on it's own, the field causing the issue might not have even been the field you were working in.